# Need Example for Setup of Sitecore Lucene Search for Sitecore v6, to index the production database

Tags: search, lucene, sitecore

I have searched high and low for a plain-english example,  with full instructions and all of the code needed,  to set up an index for my live site database on a site running Sitecore.NET 6.5.0 (rev. 111230).  The blogs from Sitecore MVP's and Sitecore's official documentation go some of the way but I'm frustrated that never have I seen a complete example, with all of the code.  I am a beginning developer, thrust into this position (yes, I know, you recommend the training - well, my employer hasn't seen fit to pay for it yet).  I have tried at least four different times using four different methods and I still don't have a search index that can find all of my live pages.  Sitecore's official documentation is incomplete and thus of no help.  So I am turning to this community.  Please help.

(Edited to refine the question, after first comment)  I know about this post [Very basic usage of sitecore search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334263/very-basic-usage-of-sitecore-search)   but get stuck on step 2.  There is a line of code there,  but what do I do with that?  I'm sorry to appear ignorant,  but I do not know what to do with that, and nowhere does any documentation go to that level of detail.  If not here, then where can I find this information?

Edit 2:  this is how I have the index configured.

```
<!-- id must be unique -->
          <index id="milo-live-index" type="Sitecore.Search.Index, Sitecore.Kernel">
            <!-- name - not sure if necessary but use id and forget about it -->
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <!-- folder - name of directory on the hard drive -->
            <param desc="folder">__milo-live-index</param>
            <!-- analyzer - reference to analyzer defined in Sitecore.config -->
            <Analyzer ref="search/analyzer" />
            <!-- list of locations to index - each of the with unique xml tag -->
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <!-- first location (and the only one in this case) - specific folder from you question -->
              <!-- type attribute is the crawler type - use default one in this scenario -->
              <specificfolder type="Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler,Sitecore.Kernel">
                <!-- indexing itmes from production database -->
                <Database>production</Database>
                <!-- your folder path -->
                <Root>/sitecore/content/homeowners</Root>
                </specificfolder>
              </locations>
```

And I go to the sitecore desktop, control panel, database / rebuild the search index, and the only index i see is the "Quick Search".

Comment: I think "specific folder" is referring to a specific part of the content tree in Sitecore, e.g. the products page and all the items under that. You should give examples of what you have and have't tried, otherwise you'dd just get referred to tutorials and other answers.

Comment: In step 2, you can rebuild your new index, from inside sitecore desktop. Log in as an admin into desktop, go to control panel->database->rebuid the search index.

Comment: It is not there.  all i see is the "quick search" index.  I have restarted the website. and still that is all I see.

Comment: In Sitecore 6.5 indexes are not added automatically to the control panel (that's a new feature starting from Sitecore 6.6 update 3 or 4). You need to rebuild them from the code as described in the post you quoted using the name of the index as a parameter.

Comment: Maybe it depends on Sitecore 6.5 revision version. I tested this today on latest (Service-Pack-2) clean Sitecore 6.5 installation and indexes are adding to control panel automatically. It also true for Service-Pack-1 (Update-5), because I created indexes in this version a few months ago and it was working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is example search index configuration. You should put this inside Web.config (under configuration/indexes) in  section

```
<index id="help_pages_index" type="Sitecore.Search.Index, Sitecore.Kernel">
    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
    <param desc="folder">help_pages_index</param>
    <Analyzer ref="search/analyzer" />
    <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
        <web-help type="Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler,Sitecore.Kernel">
            <Database>web</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore/content/Pages/Help</Root>
            <templates hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
                <helparticle>{FF48919D-393C-4F8D-9D1A-AC6B58CEC896}</helparticle>
                <helpfaq>{E66F97CF-18CF-4D73-AC84-0064D7626524}</helpfaq>
            </templates>
        </web-help>
    </locations>
</index>
```

This configuration creates new index which indexes items inside root item (/sitecore/content/Pages/Help) with one of two specified templates (helparticle, helpfaq).

After you put this to Web.config you can create simple aspx page and in Page_Load put this:

```
SearchManager.GetIndex("help_pages_index").Rebuild();
```

Execute this page once. It should rebuild your index and it should show in control panel. Alternatively you could consider to upgrade to latest version of Sitecore 6.5. In latest version index should be added automatically to control panel.

Then you can use your index from code. This example is more advanced, because it gets also hits score from lucene.

```
public class SearchHelper
{
public static SearchResults SearchHelp(string searchExpression, int start, int end)
{
    var searchResults = new SearchResults { SearchPhrase = string.Empty, TotalHits = 0, Items = new List<SearchResultItem>() };

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchExpression)) 
    {
        searchResults.SearchPhrase = searchExpression;

        var searchIndex = SearchManager.GetIndex("help_pages_index");
        if (searchIndex != null) 
        {
            using (var searchContext = searchIndex.CreateSearchContext()) 
            {
                var queryParser = new QueryParser(BuiltinFields.Content, searchIndex.Analyzer);
                queryParser.SetDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);

                var fullTextQuery = queryParser.Parse(QueryParser.Escape(searchExpression.ToLowerInvariant()));

                var languageQuery = new PhraseQuery();
                languageQuery.Add(new Term(BuiltinFields.Language, Sitecore.Context.Language.Name.ToLowerInvariant()));

                var innerQuery = new BooleanQuery();
                innerQuery.Add(fullTextQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
                innerQuery.Add(languageQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

                var hits = searchContext.Searcher.Search(innerQuery);

                var hitsLength = hits.Length();
                searchResults.TotalHits = hitsLength;
                if (hitsLength > 0 && start < hitsLength) 
                {
                    if (end >= hitsLength) 
                    {
                        end = hitsLength - 1;
                    }

                    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) 
                    {
                        var url = hits.Doc(i).Get(BuiltinFields.Url);

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) 
                        {
                            var item = Database.GetItem(ItemUri.Parse(url));

                            if (item != null && !item.Empty) 
                            {
                                searchResults.Items.Add(new SearchResultItem { Item = item, Score = hits.Score(i) });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return searchResults;
}
```

}

Comment: thank you for this.  I will give it a go in the morning and post the results.

Comment: sorry for the time delay;   I  inserted the configuration for the index, and the new index did show up in Sitecore [Sitecore.NET 6.5.0 (rev. 111230)].  I used Index Viewer to rebuild the index, and it is showing zero items.  Here is the configuration that I used:

Comment: can't edit this comment section fast enough,  and can't look up how to post code or more characters in less than five minutes.  I'm caught in a Stack overflow timeout loop  :(