# Need a method definition for MatchAllDocsQuery() for creating new Lucene in Sitecore

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

In question [Very basic usage of Sitecore search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334263/very-basic-usage-of-sitecore-search), there is an answer for creating new lucene index in Sitecore. There is a method mentioned in 3rd step called `MatchAllDocsQuery()`. So require the exact method definition for the same. I tried myself but was not up to the answer.

Comment: You just need to be sure that Lucene.dll is referenced and use `new Lucene.Net.Search.MatchAllDocsQuery()`

Comment: Note: it's not a method, it's an entire class. Notice how, in the original question, it is preceded by the `new` keyword.

Comment: Thank you Marek. Further I am facing some more issues regarding the same. Can you please look into it?

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 

Line 279:            using (IndexSearchContext indexSearchContext = SearchManager.GetIndex("Inside_master_index").CreateSearchContext())

Comment: @YuvrajKasture : Beware the [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). Please open a new question if you have one to ask.

Comment: Ok. sure i will take care of it as am new and see to it that again i wont repeat the same.