# SearchManager vs ContentSearchManager?

Tags: c#, lucene, sitecore, sitecore8

I've nerver really delved into the search capabilites of sitecore, up until now I've always used what the previous developer used. I was looking at an issue where certain predicates didn't seem to be woking in the below piece of code:

```
public IEnumerable<IndexedEvent> SearchItems(Expression<Func<IndexedEvent, bool>> predicate)
{
   using (IProviderSearchContext _context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName).CreateSearchContext())
   {
       IEnumerable<IndexedEvent> results = _context
                .GetQueryable<IndexedEvent>()
                .Where(predicate);

            return results;

   }
}
```

I didn't write the above, I'm just using it.

I was looking into my issue when I came across this example question [Very basic usage of sitecore search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334263/very-basic-usage-of-sitecore-search) which included the code:

> ```
> // use id of from the index configuration
> using (IndexSearchContext indexSearchContext = SearchManager.GetIndex("my-custom-index").CreateSearchContext())
> {
>     // MatchAllDocsQuery will return everything. Use proper query from the link below
>     SearchHits hits = indexSearchContext.Search(new MatchAllDocsQuery(), int.MaxValue);
>     // Get Sitecore items from the results of the query
>     List<Item> items = hits.FetchResults(0, int.MaxValue).Select(result => result.GetObject<Item>()).Where(item => item != null).ToList();
> }
> ```

Now this seems to use a totally different method to query the index, `IndexSearchContext` where as my code (not written by me) uses `IProviderSearchContext`. I can't find any documentation on either and they reside in totally different assemblies.

So it begs the question, when should I use `IndexSearchContext` and when should I use `IProviderSearchContext`? Is there any fundermental difference here or is it just two ways of achiving the same nett result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question and code you are referring to with the `SearchManager` and `IndexSearchContext` is from Sitecore 6. The code with the `ContentSearchManager` and `IProviderSearchContext` is for Sitecore 7 or 8 (well, 7+ that is).

So, if your code is for Sitecore8 as your tag and code example suggests, the ContentSearchManager is the way to go.